# Can't seem to find a way to use the route.php from 5.2 from laravel 5.2 to 8.83.25 web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm pretty new with Laravel, was able to work on finding a tutorial but it uses a
5.2 version.

I'm trying to convert the older version to 8.83.25

This is the route in the tutorial that I'm following.
I have created the CategoryController.php manually

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    Route::get('category', 'CategoryController');
});
```

[image: the image]

Answer (score 1):

What you used is wrong syntax. To pass a route to a controller, you are supposed to pass it as an array as such:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    Route::get('category', [CategoryController::class]);
});
```

Now supposing you want to pass it to a particular function(lets say the function `store`) in your controller, you just indicate that in the array as such:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    Route::get('category', [CategoryController::class, 'store']);
});
```

Take a look at [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing) to learn more about laravel v8 routing.

Comment: Thanks this helped me make the php artisan route:list work. I'm going to check out the docs you provided.

Comment: This syntax is correct - in older version of laravel controllers pass as string. Error, i think, appear because of controllers namespace in RouteServiceProvider